# How to find the starting and ending index of elements in list automatically in python

Tags: python

I would like to find the starting and ending index of all the userId in the list, I want to do this without specifying every single userId, because the dataset is large.

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.......213,213,213,213]
```

I want the output to be

```
[{1: 0, 20},{2: 21, 40}.....{213: 29,703, 30,000}]
```

Is there a package or function that can do this automatically in python?

Comment: `numpy.unique` with `return_index=True` will work, assuming your dataset is already sorted. If you're only using Python lists, it's probably faster to just iterate through the array yourself. It's only an O(n) operation with low overhead.

Comment: You're desired output isn't valid python. Are those values supposed to be tuples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
from collections import Counter

a = ...

a_counter = Counter(a)
a_indices = []

running_count = 0

for x, x_count in sorted(a_counter.items()):
   a_indices.append({x: (running_count, running_count + x_count - 1)}) 
   running_count += x_count
```

For example, if `a = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]`, `a_indices = [{1: (0, 1)}, {2: (2, 3)}, {3: (4, 5)}]` (closest to your output format, while being valid).

If you're willing to slightly change your output format, use:

```
a_indices = {}

running_count = 0

for x, x_count in sorted(a_counter.items()):
   a_indices[x] = (running_count, running_count + x_count - 1) 
   running_count += x_count
```

Now `a_indices`, for the `a` above, will be `{1: (0, 1), 2: (2, 3), 3: (4, 5)}`, a much nicer structure to work with.

Both of these solutions will make each end index for `x` inclusive. If you want to make it exclusive, replace `running_count + x_count - 1` with `running_count + x_count`.